# How to write Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function in terms of Meijer-G function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I am calculating a closed form expectation and I encountered the [Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#:%7E:text=Tricomi%27s%20(confluent%20hypergeometric)%20function%20U,function%20of%20the%20second%20kind.)
(aka confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind) given by integral $U\left( a,b,z \right) = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(a\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt}t^{a-1}\left(1+t\right)^{b-a-1}$. I need to write this in terms of [Meijer-G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) 
$G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left(z\left|\begin{smallmatrix}\mathbf{a}_n, \mathbf{a}_{p-n}\\
\mathbf{b}_m, \mathbf{b}_{q-m}\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)$.

I used the "MeijerGReduce[HypergeometricU[a, b, z], z] in wolfram alpha and got the solution $U(a,b,z) = \frac{G_{1,2}^{2,1}\left(z\left|\begin{smallmatrix}[1-a], [] \\
[0,1-b],[]\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)}{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(1+a-b\right)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma\left(-s\right) \Gamma\left(a+s\right) \Gamma\left(1+a-b+s\right)z^{-s}ds }{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(1+a-b\right)}$

However in the book [Handbook of Mathematical Functions: With Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables](https://books.google.com/books/about/Handbook_of_Mathematical_Functions.html?id=MtU8uP7XMvoC) it is written in terms of Barnes type integrals as follow (equaion 13.2.10 page 506)

$U(a,b,z) = \frac{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma\left(-s\right) \Gamma\left(a+s\right) \Gamma\left(1+a-b+s\right)z^{-s}ds }{\Gamma\left(a\right)\Gamma\left(1+a-b\right)z^a}$

In other words the second one has a $z^a$ term in the denominator! Which one is correct? I appreciate the hints and answers!

P.S. I copied the Wolfram answer as latex and copied it here
$\frac{\text{MeijerG}[\{\{1-a\},\{\}\},\{\{0,1-b\},\{\}\},z]}{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (a-b+1)}$. Also the solution as "input text" is
Inactive[MeijerG][{{1 - a}, {}}, {{0, 1 - b}, {}}, z]/(
Gamma[a] Gamma[1 + a - b]). Furthermore added the part from the book too!

[image]

This is also the figure that shows the solution using Wolfram Mathematica

[image]

Comment: You copied the integrand from https://www.wolframalpha.com/ incorrectly. Also, the integrals are not over closed contours.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Yes sir you are right. It was not a closed contour, I corrected my notation. Also I copied the wolfram answer as latex and also input text.

Comment: I don't understand your P.S. Anyhow, have tried to check the formulas numerically or to check their asymptotics when (say) $|z|$ goes to $0$ or $\infty$?

Comment: Why, I explained it ambiguously. In the PS I copied the answer using right click and "copy as" and pasted it above, that's it! Also could you please explain how to do that?!

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis thank you for the hint! Numerically checked it with Python. Looks like Wolfram is right and Abramowitz is wrong unfortunately! How to reference it in paper now, just referring to Wolfram I guess XD !

Comment: Unfortunately, Wolfram usually does not make its proofs available. So, I think every effort should be made to find a proof of the formula. Perhaps, there is a reference to a proof in Abramowitz--Stegun, and then it may be possible to find a mistake and fix it.